# Unable to Connect to Derby Database using Services in Netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

this is my first time to work with Derby Database and I'm having trouble in connecting to my database using the Netbeans Services.

This is the error that appears after I click my database:
[image]

But I can connect to the database using a code:
[image]

This is my database connection code:

```
private static final String DRIVER ="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
static final String JDBC_URL ="jdbc:derby:Sales_Forecast2;createdown=true;";        
public Database_Connection()
{
    try {
        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL,"sample","123456");
        try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
        if(this.con != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Connected to database");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database_Connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I've been looking for an answer but I can't get exact concern like mine.
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Netbeans is trying to use the client/server driver. Did you start the Derby database server?

Comment: @BryanPendleton Yes, I started the derby db server already. If I create database manually under Services I can connect to it, but if the database is created using source code that's the time it prompts an error.

Comment: Try using Derby's IJ tool to connect to the database using the NetBeans JDBC Connection URL, and see if you can get IJ to give you the **full** exception with more detailed clues about what sort of database open error is occurring.